# Excel crashing after running macro to work with autocad and after deleting column

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a macro to copy selected cells and paste it into specific format, it’s basically a coordinate(easting and northing) list with semicolon delimiter, and then save it into notepad.

After that my macro open autocad and call a lisp that I wrote in autocad to import the notepad into point with description. 
I use excel and autocad 2007.

My macro works as expected. However I have small irritating problem. Which is after I run the macro and the point is plotted on the autocad, if i deleted columns in excel by selecting by highlighting in the “ A B C D….” bar (For example I deleted column F to column I by highlighting the I to F bar), and then I click the “File” or “Edit” in the autocad toolbar. The excel will crash. It will close itself and then opened again in recovered mode.

When I click the “file” or “edit” the mouse cursor is showing the “thinking” animation for a second. And then the excel just crashed.
After several testing, the workaround is to perform an action in excel. For example if I copy and paste a random cell after I deleted columns, when I click the “File” or “Edit” it will not crash the excel. I’m guessing it’s a problem with the way I wrote my code and something related to selection.
It’s just that I want this code to be also used by my friends and I want it to be free of bugs.

I wonder if there’s something that I can improve in my vba code? I tried of many ways that I can think of but to no avail. 
I hope that there’s someone with similar problem that know the solution or someone that can enlighten me with the problem

```
    'This script is to draw point with description in the current active autocad drawing
'Selected cells will be concatenated to Navipac wp2 format and then saved in L:\Plot to CAD\XLtoCAD.wp2
'And then it will open autocad or if autocad already opened will tell the cad to type command "wew", which is custom LISP to draw point from wp2 

format file
'Point will be saved in layer "Point", and description will be saved in layer "Description" with magenta color
'Agung Hutomo 2016

'Public ACAD As Object
'sub to work with cad is from howtoautocad.com/excel-autocad--a-match-made-in-heaven-again/
Sub open_Cad()
Dim warning As Integer

'ENSURES USER KNOWS OPEN DRAWING WILL BE EDITED, YES NO TO PROCEED
warning = MsgBox("Selected Coordinates will be plotted into currently opened drawing." & vbCrLf & "Would you like to continue?", vbYesNo, "Data 

Loss Warning")

Select Case warning
'if they select yes to proceed
Case 6
    Set ACAD = AcadApplication 'Create ACAD variable of type AcadApplication
    On Error Resume Next 'This tells VBA to ignore errors
    Set ACAD = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application") 'Get a running instance of the class AutoCAD.Application
    On Error GoTo 0 'This tells VBA to go back to NOT ignoring errors
    If ACAD Is Nothing Then 'Check to see if the above worked
        Set ACAD = New AcadApplication 'Set the ACAD variable to equal a new instance of AutoCAD
        ACAD.Visible = True 'Once loaded, set AutoCAD® to be visible
    End If
Case 7
    Exit Sub
End Select

ACAD.ActiveDocument.SendCommand ("wew ") 'Print a message to the AutoCAD® command line
ACAD.ActiveDocument.SendCommand ("regen ")

'Inform the user that the drawing was created.
MsgBox "The coordinates was successfully exported to Autocad!", vbInformation, "Finished"

End Sub
'Sub Talk_CAD()

'End Sub
Sub concatwptocad()

'concatenate selected desc, e, n into wp2 format

    Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SelRange As Range
    Dim warn As Integer

    Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set SelRange = Selection

    ' Turn off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActSheet.Select
    SelRange.Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets.Add After:=ActSheet
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    If Range("A2") = vbNullString Then
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(char(34),RC[-3],char(34),char(59),RC[-2],char(59),RC[-1],char(59),""0.000"",char(59),14.1,char

(59),4.1,char(59),14.1,char(59),char(34),""Arial"",char(34),char(59),""0.00"",char(59),-2.1,char(59),char(34),char(34),char(59),""0.00"",char

(59),char(34),char(34),char(59),1,char(59),""0.000"",char(59),""0.000"",char(59),""0.000"",char(59),0,char(59),0.05)"

    Else

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(char(34),RC[-3],char(34),char(59),RC[-2],char(59),RC[-1],char(59),""0.000"",char(59),14.1,char

(59),4.1,char(59),14.1,char(59),char(34),""Arial"",char(34),char(59),""0.00"",char(59),-2.1,char(59),char(34),char(34),char(59),""0.00"",char

(59),char(34),char(34),char(59),1,char(59),""0.000"",char(59),""0.000"",char(59),""0.000"",char(59),0,char(59),0.05)"

    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    End If

    With Application

    If Range("A2") = vbNullString Then
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Else

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If
    Call Copytonotepad
    End With

    Call delsh


    ActSheet.Activate

    Call open_Cad
    'Call Talk_CAD


    ' Turn off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set SelRange = Nothing
    Set ActSheet = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Copytonotepad()

    Dim f As Integer, c As Range
    f = FreeFile
    Open "L:\Plot to CAD\XLtoCAD.wp2" For Output As #f
    For Each c In Selection
        Print #f, Replace(c.Value, vbLf, vbCrLf)
    Next c
    Close #f

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi com! so i commented out the set acad = acadapplication, and then did again the sequence that leading to crash. And it didn't crash this time! Thanks very much!

Comment: I also commented out the selection.copy before the call copytonotepad. I just realized that copytonotepad routine doesn't paste from copied cell.

Comment: I've reposted my comment as an "answer".  (Comments will sometimes be auto-deleted, but "answers" are more permanent.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that your statement saying `Set ACAD = AcadApplication` is a "valid" statement.  Although it appears to run in your code, I'm worried that maybe this is causing weird things to happen in memory.

Assuming `AcadApplication` is an Object type, `Set ACAD = New AcadApplication` is valid and would set the variable ACAD to be a new object of type `ACADApplication`.

`Dim ACAD As AcadApplication` is valid, and tells the compiler that ACAD will be used as an `ACADApplication` object.

But I'm not sure what happens if you set the `ACAD` variable to the object type.  It just seems like the compiler shouldn't even be allowing it to happen.

Because you immediately set `ACAD` to something else (either by your `Set ACAD = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")`, or by your `Set ACAD = New AcadApplication`) it should be safe to remove the line saying `Set ACAD = AcadApplication`.

But I've never come across the `AcadApplication` object before, so you may need to consult its documentation, just to be sure that it hasn't been designed in some unusual way.